# azure logic apps download file from link in an email

Tags: file, email, https, download, azure-logic-apps

I am currently struck with a problem and trying to solve it with azure app. I am getting an email and there is a link (https) in that email, when I click, it will download an excel file. The link will be expired after some time. I am trying azure logic app to listen to the email address and get the link from the email and download the excel file. Is it possible in azure logic apps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible using an HTTP connector. Try extracting the link from your email and pass the link to your HTTP connector. At last, you can save the content to your blob storage and download it for the same. Below is a sample that worked for me.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this was a JPEG would it work to just pass the body?